# onDisconnect not triggering when entering sleep mode?

Tags: firebase

I tested this on a couple of Mac computers, when closing the lid and entering sleep mode the onDisconnect even doesn't get triggered.

Can you guys confirm if this is a known issue and if there's a way to get around it?

Comment: Just to clarify: do you expect the `onDisconnect` to trigger on your Mac *before* it closes? Or do you have a remote client that you expect to get an `onDisconnect` for the Mac client at some point after it closes?

Comment: I assume not matter the reason Firebase should just trigger the onDisconnect when my computer goes into sleep mode.

Comment: I don't tend to assume. Which is why I ask if you can make it explicit for me.

Comment: As I said, it doesn't trigger when my computer enters sleep mode. It does trigger if I close the browser, kill the process, turn off my computer, etc.

Answer (score 1):

onDisconnect is an event that is triggered at the host (Firebase) and not on your client. It cannot fail based on the method of disconnect at the client. Once the client's socket closes (after a timeout period) the disconnect is triggered.

If it is not working, then a) the client is not actually disconnecting or b) the client does not have permission to make the changes the onDisconnect requests (e.g. does not have write permissions).

Comment: Well, it's not triggering. It works just fine if I close the browser, kill the process, etc. It doesn't trigger if I put the computer on sleep mode.

Comment: @RVera your computer doesn't necessarily disconnect from the internet when going to sleep. Not an issue with firebase imo. When in sleep mode I can still use internet apps with my mac, including stuff like air video etc.

Comment: Thank you harry, that's a reasonable explanation. The problem is that my web app is not doing anything at that point, so triggering a onDisconnect would be the sensible thing to do. Any ideas?

Comment: If it is still connected, onDisconnect will not fire. The server has no way to know if your app is not doing anything because your computer is sleeping or because it is waiting for data. Be sure to check permissions for the onDisconnect() activity. It could be that your computer is disconnecting but it cannot fire because of security restrictions.